# Extracting specific data from a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, split

Hello everyone I have a file of which consist of some random information but I only want the part that is important to me.

```
name: Zack
age: 17
As Mixed: Zack:17
Subjects opted : 3
Subject #1: Arts
name: Mike
age: 15
As Mixed: Mike:15
Subjects opted : 3
Subject #1: Arts
```

Above is a example of my text file I want **Zack:17** and **Mike:15** part to be written in a text file and everything else to be ignored.

I watched some YouTube videos and came across split statement in python but it didn't work.

My code example

```
with open("/home/ninja/Desktop/raw.txt","r") as raw:
    for rec in raw:
        print rec.split('As Mixed: ')[0]
```

This didn’t work.
Any help will really help me to finish this project.
Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you create a data frame with the information you want and then write it?

Comment: try `open(os.path.join(root, textfile), "r").readlines()[specified_line:]`

Comment: What does "it did not work" mean? Did you get an exception? If so, whcih one? Can you include the *full* traceback you get (starting from `Traceback (most recent call ...` up to `ExceptionType: <message>`? The result was not what you expected? Then which result did you expect and which you got instead? Did the program crash (e.g. the program was terminated with `Segmentation fault`)? Also: the syntax you are using is python2 syntax, why did you include the python-3.x tag? The only case in which you should use two version specific tags are for porting questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the data at the `:` and grab only `As Mixed` parameter

```
content = [i.strip('\n').split(': ') for i in open('filename.txt')]
results = [b for a, b in content if a.startswith('As Mixed')]
```

Output:

```
['Zack:17', 'Mike:15']
```

To write the results to a file:

```
with open('filename.txt', 'w') as f:
  for i in results:
    f.write(f'{i}\n')
```

Comment: I tried this but got this error ValueError: too many values to unpack

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import re
found = []
match = re.compile('(Mike|Zack):(\w*)')
with open('/hope/ninja/Destop/raw.twt', "r") as raw:
    for rec in raw:
        found.extend(match.find_all(rec))

print(found)
#output: [('Mike', '15'), ('Zack', '17')]
```

This uses regular expressions to find the value needed, basically `(Mike|Zack):(\w*)` finds Mike or Zack and then a `:` character and then as many word as it can find.
To learn more about regular expressions you can read from this website: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html